# \listofschemes from chemmacros not working with KOMA script commands

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, chemmacros

I want to change the appearance of my listoffigures, listoftables, and listofschemes with KOMA script commands.

I use the scheme environment from the chemmacros package.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,
                            twoside,
                            paper=b5,
                            pagesize=auto,
                            numbers=noenddot,                % Removes ending point after heading- and caption numbers.
                            toc=bibliography,                % Includes bibliography into ToC but without numbering it.
                            listof=totoc,                    % Includes all lists (figures, etc.) into ToC but without numbering.
                            open=right,                      % Start new chapters on a right page (doublepage layout).
                            singlespacing=true,              % KOMA-script. p 450ff. setspace only in textbody.
                            chapterprefix=true,
                            appendixprefix=true
                            ]{scrreprt}                                  
%
\usepackage{scrhack}                             % Patches for KOMA-script.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                 
\usepackage[final,tracking=true]{microtype}                                     
\usepackage{fontspec}                            
\defaultfontfeatures{
 Ligatures = TeX ,                           
     RawFeature={+calt} ,                        
 SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
 }                
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,
                    bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}                                   
\usepackage{libertinus}                                                      
%
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{float}                                                                      
\usepackage{chemmacros}                                          
\usechemmodule{mechanisms,%                      
                         redox,%                           
                         spectroscopy,%
                         units,%
                         scheme}
 \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thescheme}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{scheme}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{scheme}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:1}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:2}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:3}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:4}
\end{scheme}
%
\blindtext
%
\listoffigures
\listofschemes
%
\end{document}
```

While

> \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{figure}

works nice for figures and tables (not shown), trying to do the same for the scheme environment results in the following error:

```
! Package tocbasic Error: toc style `dottedtocline' needs toc entry level.

See the tocbasic package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.42 ...t=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{scheme}

Usually the toc entry level is defined using option `level'.
In some cases it may be set defining command `\schemetocdepth'.
If you'll continue, I'll ignore the command. This could result in
further error messages.
```

According to the chemmacros documentation, the scheme environment should be compatible with KOMA script, so I wonder what causes the error in the .log file.

The output is also not consistent, as the listoffigures is formatted according to the commands, while the listofschemes is still starting with an indent, see pictures below:
[image]
[image]

Any ideas how to solve this formatting issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `chemmacros` checkes at begin document if a KOMA-Script class is used or if package `tocbasic` is loaded manually (with another class). Then it defines the new list for the `schemes` using  `\DeclareNewTOC`. So you have to defer the change of `indent` and `numwidth` for TOC entries `scheme` using `\AtBeginDocument`, too.

Use

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{default}{scheme}}
```

to ensure that `scheme` is already defined by `chemmacros` when you change its `indent` and `numwidth`. Note that you do the same for your redefinition of `\thescheme`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,
  twoside,
  paper=b5,
  pagesize=auto,
  numbers=noenddot,
  toc=bibliography,
  listof=totoc,
  open=right,
  %singlespacing=true,% not used in the example
  chapterprefix=true,
  appendixprefix=true
  ]{scrreprt}
%
\usepackage{scrhack}% Patches for KOMA-script.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
%
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{mechanisms,%
  redox,%
  spectroscopy,%
  units,%
  scheme}
 \AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\thescheme}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{scheme}}%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{default}{scheme}% <- moved
}
%
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{default}{figure}
%
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:1}
\end{scheme}
\chapter{Another chapter}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:2}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:3}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:4}
\end{scheme}
%
\blindtext
\listoffigures
\listofschemes
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @esdd, seems like the solution was already in the code and I just didn't saw the analogy... Now it works like a charm, so thx for that!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems that `chemmacros` (2017) is based on an meanwhile changed version of `tocbasic` of KOMA-Script.

You should contact the maintainer of `chemmacros` and write an bug report (if you want you can use this question/answer as example).

A quick workaround can be to simply add the following lines in your preamble (please see important code changes marked with `<=========`):

```
\DeclareNewTOC[% <======================================================
  type=scheme,%
  types=schemes,%
  float,% Gleitumgebungen sollen definiert werden.
  floattype=4,%
  name=Scheme,%
  listname={List of schemes}%
]{scheme}
\setuptoc{scheme}{chapteratlist} % <====================================
```

So with the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=10pt,
  twoside,
  paper=b5,
  pagesize=auto,
  numbers=noenddot,                % Removes ending point after heading- and caption numbers.
  toc=bibliography,                % Includes bibliography into ToC but without numbering it.
  listof=totoc,                    % Includes all lists (figures, etc.) into ToC but without numbering.
  open=right,                      % Start new chapters on a right page (doublepage layout).
  singlespacing=true,              % KOMA-script. p 450ff. setspace only in textbody.
  chapterprefix=true,
  appendixprefix=true
]{scrreprt}                                  
%
\usepackage{scrhack}                             % Patches for KOMA-script.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                 
%\usepackage[final,tracking=true]{microtype} % <================================                                    
\usepackage{fontspec}                            
\defaultfontfeatures{
 Ligatures = TeX ,                           
     RawFeature={+calt} ,                        
 SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}
 }                
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,
                    bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}                                   
\usepackage{libertinus}                                                      
%
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{float}                                                                      
\usepackage[compatibility=newest]{chemmacros} % <=======================
\usechemmodule{%
  mechanisms,%                      
  redox,%                           
  spectroscopy,%
  units,%
  scheme
}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thescheme}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{scheme}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{figure}
\DeclareNewTOC[% <======================================================
  type=scheme,%
  types=schemes,%
  float,% Gleitumgebungen sollen definiert werden.
  floattype=4,%
  name=Scheme,%
  listname={List of schemes}%
]{scheme}
\setuptoc{scheme}{chapteratlist} % <====================================
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0em,numwidth=2.3em]{dottedtocline}{scheme}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
%
\blindtext
%
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:1}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:2}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:3}
\end{scheme}
\begin{scheme}[H]
\caption{blabla}
  \label{scheme:4}
\end{scheme}
%
\blindtext
%
\listoffigures
\listofschemes
%
\end{document}
```

I get the following resulting scheme list:

[image: resulting scheme list]

Please see: **That is only a workaround,** 
the maintainer should be asked to correct the package!

Comment: Package `chemmacros` does not have a problem with a `tocbasic` version.

Comment: Additionally a new list defined by `\DeclareNewTOC` gets `owner=float` by default. So it uses the same settings as LOF and LOT (`listof=...` or `chapteratlist`) automatically.